# Trying to figure out arrays and recursion within a class

Tags: c++, class, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am implementing a matrix class for an assignment, and I find myself trying to adapt a previous code of mine into the class without success, this particular function is for the determinant of a given matrix, I am not sure how to work with the arrays as parameters of the function such that it keeps working with the recursion, specially when it pertains to the "aux" array, outside of the class it helps to pass the matrices of cofactors into the recursion, I have given some thought to this for a couple of weeks already without any success and I am not sure how else to tackle this, so any kind of advise on how to proceed would be appreciated.

```
class matriz
{
    fracc m[10][10];

    int a=0, b=0;

    public:
        matriz();
        void rand_populate();
        void printm();
        void user_populate();
        fracc non_verbose_det(fracc, int);
        matriz operator+(matriz);
        matriz operator-(matriz);
        matriz operator*(matriz);
};


fracc matriz::non_verbose_det(fracc, int g)
{   
    int n1=0, n2=0;
    fracc aux[3][3];
    fracc det=m[0][0] * m[1][1] - m[1][0] * m[0][1];
    fracc d=aux[0][0] * aux[1][1] - aux[1][0] * aux[0][1];

    if(g==1)
    {   
        return 0;
    }
    else if(g==2)
    {   
        return det;
    }


       for(int k=0;k<g;k++)
       {   
            n1=0;
            n2=0;
            for(int i=1;i<g;i++)
            {   
                n1=0;
                for(int j=0;j<g;j++)
                {   
                    if(j==k)
                    {
                        j++;
                    }

                    aux[n2][n1]=m[i][j];
                    n1++;
                }
                n2++;
        }

            if (k%2==0)
            {   
                if (g==2)
                {
                    d=d+m[0][k]*non_verbose_det(aux, g-1);
                }
                else if(g!=2 && k==0)
                {
                    d=d*m[0][1]+non_verbose_det(aux, g-1)*m[0][0];
                }
                else if(g!=2 && k!=0)
                {
                    d=d+non_verbose_det(aux, g-1)*m[0][k];
                }

            }
            else
            {        
                if (a==2)
                {
                    d=d-m[0][k]*non_verbose_det(aux, g-1);
                }
                else if(g!=2 && k==0)
                {
                    d=d*m[0][1]-non_verbose_det(aux, g-1)*m[0][0];
                }
                else if(g!=2 && k!=0)
                {
                    d=d-non_verbose_det(aux, g-1)*m[0][k];
                }
            }
        }
    return d;  
}
```

Comment: `fracc non_verbose_det(int);` and `fracc matriz::non_verbose_det(fracc, int g)` have different parameters

Comment: indeed apologies, I copied another version of the code for the class declaration by accident, modifying the parameters back however still gives several errors like the fallowing:
**257 7 C:\Users\Chraos\Downloads\class_matrix.cpp [Error] prototype for 'fracc matriz::non_verbose_det(fracc (*)[3], int)' does not match any in class 'matriz'**

and tbh I am not even sure whats going on with that error.

Comment: Why does the function expect two arguments if you don't use the first one?

Comment: mostly I am at a try and error stage at this point, since I am at a lost at a lost in how to proceed, one is supposed to take the size of the matrix and the other one, the "aux" matrix, but can't get it to work properly :/.